# Ruby hello world in sublime

Tags: ruby

I am trying to run my first Ruby program. I am using sublime. My programs code is as follows..

```
$ vim helloworld.rb

#!/usr/bin/ruby

# Hello world ruby program

puts "Hello World!";
```

I am getting the following output error...

> C:/Users/myname/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text
>   2/Packages/User/helloworld.rxml:1: `$ ' is not allowed as a global
>   variable name [Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]

Can anyone help me, and google search did not turn up much.

Comment: what is this *$ vim helloworld.rb* ? remove it

Comment: hmmm you probably mistaken a console command with actual code in file from the tutorial you reading?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove  `$ vim helloworld.rb` from the file.

It's a common practice in the books to prefix the commands written in terminal with `$`, so if you see `$ some_cmd`, it's most probably written in terminal.